# How to create/add multiple tittles and border lines to one text table in Tableau Desktop

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I have a text table in Tableau Desktop that looks like this.

[image]

I want to partition it to add multiple tittles with border lines to separate into three parts within one tableau sheet, expecting result to look like this.

[image]

Any ideas on how to achieve that? or if it's even possible in Tableau Desktop? Version 2022.1.10

Comment: you can't achieve that within a single worksheet, but you can get something closer using multiple worksheets and then using the layout pane when finalizing your dashboard